# Deploying a Docker Image from Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, docker

I have pushed a working docker image to Azure Container Registry. I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tutorial-deploy-app) to deploy it as a web application.

I followed the steps and it created a new web application, but it does not contain any files other than default Azure html that says `Your App Service app is up and running`. I am trying to figure out what went wrong. I checked the `Activity logs` and it says nothing. I checked the debug console `<my-site>.scm.azurewebsites.net`, and it does not contain any of the `Docker Image` files. How can I check what went wrong during the deployment?

---

Here is what I did.

- I created a docker image, let's just call it `my-image`.
- I checked it is working fine on my local machine.
- I created a new tag to push the image to acr, `docker tag <my-image_id> my-acr-username.azurecr.io/my-image`.
- Then I pushed it to acr, `docker push my-acr-username.azurecr.io/my-image`
- I checked the acr repository to verify if it is pushed successfully.
- Then I followed the above mentioned tutorial to deploy the image.

P.S. I am using Windows Containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Windows Containers, and it turns out that Azure does not have a support for it yet. Unfortunately, it does not give you any errors or warnings if you try to deploy Windows Container. It simply doesn't work, and the user wonders what went wrong...

Here is [my issue](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2690) on their deployment engine `Kudu`.